# How to display custom query results with $wpdb class

Tags: wordpress

here is my custom sql query ;

```
$wpdb->prefix .'mariapostvote';
$query = "SELECT sum(vote_point) as total_votes,count(id) as toplam FROM 'wp_mariapostvote' WHERE post_id = '13793'";
```

how can print the result correctly with `$wpdb` class?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your answers

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable

For a var, you can do

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var($query);
echo $result /* Print the result */
```